# Odoo8: ValueERROR: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, odoo-8

I'm Inheriting Function in Account Voucher (def voucher_move_line_create) using new api style odoo8.

Here's my Code:

```
@api.model
def voucher_move_line_create(self, line_total, move_id, company_currency, current_currency):
    res =  super(AccountVoucher, self).voucher_move_line_create(line_total, move_id, company_currency, current_currency)
    _logger.info('\n\n\n Return: %s \n\n\n'%(str(res)))
    for i in res[1]:
        _logger.info('\n\n\nRes Return: %s \n\n\n'%(str(i)))
    return res
```

and I Got this Error:

File "/opt/odoo8/odoo8-server/openerp/api.py", line 769, in **new**
    self.cr, self.uid, self.context = self.args = (cr, uid, frozendict(context))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you forgot an argument while you're inheriting this function.
You missed **voucher_id** argument so the inherited function should be like :

```
@api.model
def voucher_move_line_create(self, voucher_id, line_total, move_id, company_currency, current_currency):
        res =  super(account_voucher, self).voucher_move_line_create(voucher_id, line_total, move_id, company_currency, current_currency)
```

I hope this helps, and thank you for your question.